# Proof that Alternating Step Generator and modifed ASG' have equivalent security?

Tags: cryptanalysis, random-number-generator, stream-cipher, alternating-step

The [Alternating Step Generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_step_generator) (ASG) is a PRNG combining 3 LFSRs. Output of the ASG is the XOR of the output of two clock-gated LFSRs. At each step, a single one of these LFSRs is clocked, according to the output of the control LFSR.

The best (AFAIK) claimed attack on the ASG is [Reduced Complexity Attacks on the ASG](http://www.simonfischer.ch/science/sac07.pdf) [(Slides)](http://www.simonfischer.ch/science/sac07_talk.pdf). However it attacks a variant ASG', which output is the output of the clock-gated LFSR that was clocked.

Justification given in that paper is: *It is known [[13](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.25.4609), [8](ftp://ftp.hacktic.nl/pub/mirrors/Advances%20in%20Cryptology/HTML/PDF/C97/499.PDF), [12](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.113.3495)] that instead of working with the original definition of ASG we can consider a slightly different description (..)*.
[[13](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.25.4609)] only states *It is not hard to show that ASG and ASG’ are equivalent (..)* with no argument. I fail to find a discussion about ASG' in [[8](ftp://ftp.hacktic.nl/pub/mirrors/Advances%20in%20Cryptology/HTML/PDF/C97/499.PDF)]. [[12](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.113.3495)] has a constructive proof, but I fail to get it (unless I assume that one of the LFSR is known/enumerated).

Any clue on a proof/sketch/argument that an attack on ASG' reconstructing the initial states of the LFSRs can be turned into an equally efficient attack on ASG?

Comment: Please ignore the following comments, they are formatting tests for [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/349979/184379).

Comment: For $\LaTeX$/MathJax see [this](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1070/555). $n=1$.

Comment: For $\LaTeX$ /MathJax see [this](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1070/555). $n=1$.

Comment: For $\LaTeX$/MathJax see [this](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1070/555).

Comment: For $\LaTeX$+MathJax see [this](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1070/555). $n=1$.

Comment: For $\LaTeX$-MathJax see [this](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1070/555). $n=1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, I had a look at your source [[12](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.113.3495)], e.g. *ON EDIT DISTANCE ATTACK TO ALTERNATING STEP GENERATOR*.

The original ASG defines the key stream Z = {z_i} from three shift registers X = {x_i}, Y = {y_i} and C = {c_i} via these steps:

> 1. Initially, l = 0, t = 1.
> 2. If ct = 1, then l = l + 1;
> 3. Output z_t = x_l ⊕ y_(t−l) , where ⊕ is XOR operator;
> 4. t = t + 1 and go to step 2.

E.g. we step one them depending on c_t, and use the latest output of both.

---

For the variant, we define w_i = z_i ⊕ z_(i-1), u_i = x_i ⊕ x_(i-1), v_i = y_i ⊕ y_(i-1), e.g simply the "difference sequences" of the original ones.

U = {u_i} and V = {v_i} can easily be created by LFSRs of the same length as these for X and Y, simply by adding or removing one feedback link. (And if we have the registers for U and V, we can get the registers for X and Y back.)

It now shows that we can derive W = {w_i} not only directly from Z, but also from U, V and C, using the modified construction:

> 1. Initially l = 0, t = 1;
> 2. If c_t = 1, then l = l + 1 and output w_t = u_l ;
> 3. If c_t = 0, output w_t = v_(t−l).
> 4. t = t + 1, go to step 2.

Why? Simply put the formulas:

If c_t = 1, then

```
w_t =      z_t        ⊕        z_(t-1)
    = (x_l ⊕ y_(t−l)) ⊕ (x_(l-1) ⊕ y_((t-1)−(l-1)))
    = (x_l ⊕ x_(l-1)) ⊕ (y_((t-1)−(l-1)) ⊕ y_(t−l))
    =      u_l        ⊕ (y_(t−l) ⊕ y_(t−l))
    =      u_l        ⊕         0
    =      u_l.
```

If c_t = 0, then

```
w_t =     z_t         ⊕     z_(t-1)
    = (x_l ⊕ y_(t−l)) ⊕ (x_l ⊕ y_((t-1)−l))
    = (x_l ⊕ x_l) ⊕ (y_(t−l) ⊕ y_((t-1)−l)
    =       0     ⊕ (y_(t−l) ⊕ y_((t-l)−1)
    =       0     ⊕      v_(t-l)
    =                    v_(t-l).
```

It is a bit confusing because of `1` and `l` looking quite similar here.

**So, how would we do our attack on Z, given an attack on W?**

1. Transform the observed sequence of Z into a sequence for W, by calculating differences of consecutive elements.
2. Break W, get formulas for C, U and V.
3. Transform the formulas for U and V back into these for X and Y by adding/removing
   one feedback link.

Comment: A minor detail: while the "difference sequence" U for X has the same linear complexity as X, going from one to the other is not quite adding or removing a tap. E.g. with the poly x^2+x+1 the sequence X is 110110110110.., U is 01101101101.. and has the same poly. Which is not surprising as there

Comment: More generally, adding or removing a coefficient from a primitive polynomial leaves us with a non-primitive polynomial, so the relationship must be something else. It remains that an attack breaking **ANY** ASG' (for some polynomial sizes) with some probability breaks any ASG (with same polynomial sizes).

Comment: You are right, simply adding/removing a link does not fit it - we would need a link from the original register, not from our own register.

Comment: Thinking about it: the "difference sequence" U for X uses the same polynomial as X, just a different initial state, which can be obtained by XORing the initial state of X, and its states after one step. Getting back from U to X is nearly as trivial. Therefore, we do not need the **ANY** in my above comment.

Answer (score 0):

Please ignore this answer, it is a formatting test for [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/349979/184379).

For $\LaTeX$/MathJax see [this](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1070/555). $n=1$.